# Levin & Peres 2017 Ex. 4.1: prove that $\overline{d}(t)=\sup_{\mu,\nu}\lVert\mu P^t-\nu P^t\rVert_{TV}$

Tags: markov-chains

> **Definition** Let $S$ be a finite set. For any probability distributions $\mu,\nu$ on $S$,
> $$\lVert\mu-\nu\rVert_{TV}:=\max_{A\subset S}|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|\text{.}$$
> Let $P$ be a transition kernel with state space $S$. For any positive interger $t$,
> $$\overline{d}(t):=\max_{x,y\in S}\lVert P^t(x,\cdot)-P^t(y,\cdot)\rVert_{TV}\text{.}$$

> Prove that $$\overline{d}(t)=\sup\lVert\mu P^t-\nu P^t\rVert_{TV}$$
> where the supremum is taken over all distributions $\mu,\nu$ on $S$.

That $\mbox{LHS}\leq\mbox{RHS}$ is clear. For any distributions $\mu,\nu$ on $S$ and $A\subset S$,
$$\begin{align*}|\mu P^t(A)-\nu P^t(A)|&=|\sum_x\mu(x)P^t(x,A)-\sum_x\mu(x)P^t(y,A)+\sum_x\nu(x)P^t(y,A)-\sum_x\nu(x)P^t(x,A)|\\
&=|\sum_x(\mu(x)-\nu(x))(P^t(x,A)-P^t(y,A))|
\end{align*}$$
for any $y\in S$.

I don't know how to proceed any further.

Comment: Fwiw Peres is a user of this site

Comment: Use the alternative equivalent definition of total variation distance $$2||\mu-\nu|| = \sum_{y \in S} |\mu\{y\}-\nu\{y\}|.$$ RHS $\le$ LHS will follow by triangular inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose by way of contradiction that
$$\sup_{\mu,\nu \in \Delta(S)} \|\mu P^t - \nu P^t\|_{TV} > \sup_{x,y \in S} \|P^t(x,\cdot) - P^t(y,\cdot)\|_{TV},$$
where $\Delta(S)$ is the set of probability measures over $S$.

Let $\mu, \nu \in \Delta(S)$ and $A \subset S$ such that
$$\mu P^t(A) - \nu P^t(A) > \sup_{x,y \in S} \|P^t(x,\cdot) - P^t(y,\cdot)\|_{TV}.$$
Note that $\mu \mapsto \mu P^t(A)$ is linear, hence it is maximized for $\mu = \delta_x$ for some $x \in S$, where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac measure. Similarly $\nu \mapsto \nu P^t(A)$ is minimized for $\nu = \delta_y$ for some $x \in S$. Hence
$$\mu P^t(A) - \nu P^t(A) \leq P^t(x,A) - P^t(y,A) \leq \sup_{x,y\in S} \|P^t(x,\cdot) - P^t(y,\cdot)\|_{TV},$$
contradiction.

Comment: A proof by contradiction is not needed, you can immediately show the last inequality for any $A\subset S$ and any two $\mu,\nu$.